# Creating an object from a chunk of R code without converting to a string

Tags: r, parsing, eval

I am trying to turn an arbitrary chunk (not in the `Rmarkdown`sense) of code into an object that I can call to return either (1) the code's output or (2) the code and its output.

I can produce output (1) by converting the code to a string and then use `eval(parse())`. However, the issue with this approach is that turning the code into a string means syntax highlighters and linters do not look at the contents of the string and this makes it more difficult to debug. I am therefore looking for alternative approaches. Below I demonstrate what I'm looking for.

### Start with a chunk of arbitrary code

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
print(5)
#> [1] 5
df$x + 1
#>  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

### Current Approach: convert chunk to string

```r
my_code <- "
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
print(5)
df$x + 1
"
eval(parse(text = my_code))
#> [1] 5
#>  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

### Desired Approach (psuedo-code): wrap chunk in `foo{}`, call object

```r
# Wrap in some function
my_code <- foo{
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
print(5)
df$x + 1
}
```

### Two possible types of outputs expected

##### Output option #1: shows code, shows output

```r
# Call object
my_code

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
print(5)
#> [1] 5
df$x + 1
#>  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

##### Output #2: doesn't show code, shows output

```r
# Call object
my_code
#> [1] 5
#>  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: @Dave2e While I can use the `Rmarkdown` package, as well as `pandoc` and `knitr`, I am looking for a solution that can be implemented in a .R file.

Comment: For your output option #1 See the "reprex" package, (https://reprex.tidyverse.org) that might work for you.  The package doesn't appear to have an option to suppress the code and leave the output.

Comment: Yes, I played around with some of the ideas in reprex...the issue being that it only appears to accept one expression at a time or that I would need to somehow create a single expression from the chunk. Latter seems possible but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I mean.. maybe I misunderstood you, but isn't that exactly what functions are used for? To give a name to a chunk of code that is executed later by referring to that name?

Comment: @AEF Functions introduce issues with local environments and returning objects. See comment on your proposed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `quote()` your code. To execute use `eval()`, to print you can coerce to character and `cat()`:

```r
# Quote code
code <- quote(
  {
    df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
    print(5)
    df$x + 1
  }
)

# Execute code
eval(code)
#> [1] 5
#>  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

# Print code
code |> 
  as.character() |>
  (`[`)(-1) |> 
  paste(collapse = "\n") |> 
  cat()
#> df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
#> print(5)
#> df$x + 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Closest to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need are classic nullary functions. They basically just give a name to chunk of code in order to execute it later:

```
## define function
my_code <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
  print(5)
  df$x + 1
}

## show code
body(my_code)

#   {
#     df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
#     print(5)
#     df$x + 1
#   }

## show output
my_code()

#   [1] 5
#    [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

If it's important to you that you can execute the code without adding parentheses you can use what is called 'active binding'. I would not recommend it, though.

```
## Variant with active binding:
makeActiveBinding("my_code", function(){
  
  df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
  print(5)
  df$x + 1
  
}, .GlobalEnv)

## show output
my_code

#   [1] 5
#    [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: Wrapping it in a function introduces (a) scoping issues (calling `my_code()` does not return `df` in the global environment) and (b) cannot return multiple objects (add `df$x + 3` above `df$x + 1` in the body of the function, you'll see only `df$x + 1` is returned). Both could be avoided with some modification to the original code, but I'm trying to not modify the original code at all.

 is not in the global environment w